# Lipschitz continuous function of a matrix

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

What is the definition of Lipschitz continuous function of a matrix?

Suppose $f$ is a function of a matrix.

The definition should be something like

$$\| f(X+S) - \ f(X) \| \le \nu \|S\| $$
But I am not sure which matrix norm I should use?
Does it matter which matrix norm we use? Where can I find relevant stuff?

What if $f$ is from matrices to matrices?

Comment: In finite-dimensional vector spaces all norms are equivalent.

Comment: why gradient of $f$. The definition is the same as the usual definition. Consider a Matrix in $R^{n\times m}$ as a vector in $R^{nm}$

Comment: What does equivalent mean? Equivalent in terms of Lipschitz continuity? I.e. It does not matter which one I pick, or you are saying something even stronger? :)

Comment: Thanks Quickbeamer2k1  I just fixed that part....

Comment: @user25004 The statement that two norms $\| x \|_1$ and $\| x \|_2$ are equivalent means that there exist constants $c,C>0$ such that for every $A$ in the normed space, $c \| x \|_1 \leq \| x \|_2 \leq C \| x \|_1$. This means a number of things; in particular it means that there is only one topology induced by a norm on any finite dimensional space. It also means that a function is either Lipschitz or not, it doesn't depend on the norm. The *constant* depends on the norm, but whether *some* constant exists does not.

Comment: As Ivo Terek pointed out: the property of a function being Lipschitz continuous is (in finite dimensional spaces) independent of the norm you choose. And this is somehow really astonishing :)

Comment: $f$ is not multivalued if it maps to matrices but a function that maps from $R^{n\times m}$ to $R^{k\times l}$. Now check my first comment :) The norms on the spaces are "irrelevant" as pointed out earlier.

Comment: ^Typo, it should be every $x$ of course, not every $A$.